# Reading From A Text File - Batch

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I have a text file, a.txt:

> Hello World 
>   Good Afternoon

I have written a batch script to read contents of this file line by line:
`FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (a.txt) DO echo %%x`

I am getting output as `"Hello" "World"` due to default behaviour of delimiter(space).
How can I override this behaviour to get the ouptut as `"Hello World" "Good Afternoon"`

Comment: Your code solves your problem, you should test it again

Comment: You're script works for me.

Comment: No. Its not giving desired output. 
It is breaking line with space character

Comment: yea you are right, its giving correct output.
I am passing these values to vbs file.
In vbs file i am facing this problem while reading arguments through `WScript.Arguments`

Comment: maybe try `echo "%%x"` to pass the echo as one argument if that's what you're after.

Comment: I enclosed parameters within double quotes while passing to vbs file. problem solved!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code "for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (a.txt) do echo %%x" will work on most Windows Operating Systems unless you have modified commands.

So you could instead "cd" into the directory to read from before executing the "for /f" command to follow out the string. For instance if the file "a.txt" is located at C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop\a.txt then you'd use the following.

```
cd "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (a.txt) do echo %%x
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
exit
```

But since this doesn't work on your computer for x reason there is an easier and more efficient way of doing this. Using the "type" command.

```
@echo off
color a
cls
cd "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop"
type a.txt
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
exit
```

Or if you'd like them to select the file from which to write in the batch you could do the following.

```
@echo off
:A
color a
cls
echo Choose the file that you want to read.
echo.
echo.
tree
echo.
echo.
echo.
set file=
set /p file=File:
cls
echo Reading from %file%
echo.
type %file%
echo.
echo.
echo.
set re=
set /p re=Y/N?:
if %re%==Y goto :A
if %re%==y goto :A
exit
```

Comment: How value will be assigned to \%USERNAME%\ parameter?