# How can I read a line from .txt file and compare it to user input in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm fairly new to CMD but I keep experimenting and searching a lot about it and I've came to a dead-end.
So my question is this:
Is is possible for a batch file to read a certain line from a .txt file, and then 
compare it to some user input? In essence, what I want to create is to have a standart .txt file (which will be holding some information) and a batch file which, once initiated, will be asking the user for some information, and then compare that with a specific .txt file line to see wether the user input matches the info in the .txt. So far, the comparison is what I cannot code. Any help? 
Thanks. ;)

Comment: Have you even tried to google for it? Go step by step with searching... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834625/reading-text-file-in-batch-script  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com

Answer (score 0):

You can read the textfile into a variable using SET. 
For example, place a file `data.txt` on the desktop containing the word `password`. Then put this in your batch file:

```
@echo off
SET /p txt=<%userprofile%\Desktop\data.txt

IF "%1" == "%txt%" (
    ECHO "%1 matched!"
) ELSE (
    ECHO "%1 did not match"
)
```

If you run:
`test.bat wrongpassword` the output is: `"wrongpassword did not match"`

However, if you run: `test.bat password` the output is `"password matched!"`

Side Note: storing and checking a password like this would be a really really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with looping through your "test.txt" file on your desktop that could look as follows:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
data9
```

And "test.bat" file then:

```
set /p @var= Add your input here: 
cls
ECHO Script initiated!
ECHO %@var%

cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\desktop"

:: loop over file line by line
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
:: test if data exist in file
IF %@var%==%%a (
     echo data exists in txt file
    )
)
pause
```

Try to type as input: "data4" and you will see that after fourth loop data4 is outputed.